# Standard longitudinal health dataset

Tags: database

I am looking for a specific type of a dataset in order to develop a statistical and/or machine learning model for health data. This dataset should contain histories of many patients with the diagnoses/procedures that they underwent and the corresponding time labels. I would like to hope that there is such a dataset (or similar) used for machine learning algorithms, which is freely available and not constrained by patient privacy issues, etc.

All suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [ipums.org](https://ipums.org/). They have two sources that may be beneficial to you:

Health Surveys: Historical and contemporary U.S. health survey data from the National Health Interview Survey (NHIS) (1963-present) and the Medical Expenditure Panel Survey (MEPS) (1996-present).

Global Health: Health survey data for Africa and Asia, including harmonized data collections for Demographic Health Surveys (DHS) and Performance Monitoring for Action (PMA)